How to integrate icons into an angular library?
I would like to integrate an SVG icons into my angular library's template, and I have the following questions?

Where should the /assets folder be located? Should it reside under /src or /src/lib within the library structure?
What modifications are required in the ng-package.json and/or angular.json files?
How should SVG icons be referenced in the component templates? Should they be referenced using relative paths, absolute paths, or does it not matter?

How can I achieve this, please?

Where should the /assets folder be located?
In an Angular library, the recommended location for the /assets folder is under /src, not /src/lib. This ensures that the assets are bundled correctly when the library is built and consumed in applications.
Structure: projects/src/assets/icons/icon.svg
ng-package.json and/or angular.json Modifications
angular.json
{
  "projects": {
    "library-name": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

ng-package.json
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "assets": [
    "src/assets"
  ]
}

In the component templates
Use a relative path like this
<img src="assets/icons/my-icon.svg" alt="My Icon">

Use relative paths ensures that the assets are packaged with the library and work seamlessly when the library is consumed in different environments.

Thank you for your answer although your solution seems to not work. The console shows the following error:  "GET http://localhost:4200/assets/icons/my-icon.svg 404 (Not Found)".
